# How to add/indicate x, y, cell size when creating Netcdf?

Tags: matlab, matrix, netcdf, dimension

I have a netcdf file (variables `x`, `y`, `lat`, `lon`, `crs`, `time`, `temperature`), 300x300x8760 matrix. The grid is 5000x5000m.
I've defined a new netcdf with the temperature average by a 300x300 matrix. The new variables have the characteristics of the original attributes. But when I import this new file to GIS programs the grid cell 5000x5000m passes to 1x1.

Is there any dimension/length issue am I missing when working in MATLAB?

Here is  part of the code where `x`, `y` are created:

```
xf = ncread('Temperature.nc','x'); %f stands for "filtered"
xf = ncread('Temperature.nc','x'); %f stands for "filtered"
yf = ncread('Temperature.nc','y');
crsf= ncread('Temperature.nc','crs');
lonf = ncread('Temperature.nc','lon');
latf = ncread('Temperature.nc','lat');
tmpf=zeros(300);

for i = 1:300
    for j = 1:300
        tempf = ncread('Temperature.nc','Temperature',[i j 1], [1 1 8760]);
        tmpf(i,j)= mean(tempf); % Average of 8760 elements
    end
end

%New nc file and variables creation
nccreate('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','Datatype','single','Dimensions', {'x',300});
ncwrite('tmpfiltered.nc','xf',xf); % writing x
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','long_name','x-coordinate');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','standard_name','projection_x_coordinate');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','units','m');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','axis','X');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','valid_min',-20000000);
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','valid_max',20000000);
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','xf','grid_mapping','crs');

% y variable
nccreate('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','Datatype','single','Dimensions',{'y',300});
ncwrite('tmpfiltered.nc','yf',yf);
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','long_name','y-coordinate');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','standard_name','projection_y_coordinate');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','units','m');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','axis','Y');
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','valid_min',-20000000);
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','valid_max',20000000);
ncwriteatt('tmpfiltered.nc','yf','grid_mapping','crs');
```

Any tip?